# Replace part of a matched regexp with sed or any other tool

Tags: awk, sed

I need to replace a character on file portions matching a certain regexp. To be precise, I need to remove spaces with `-` in ill-formed markdown links, e.g.:

```
[This is my link](actual bad link.md)
```

should become:

```
[This is my link](actual-bad-link.md)
```

I can match something that begins with `(` and ends with `.md)` with a regexp in sed, but then I don't know how to tell sed to replace only the spaces in the matched expression. Is there a way to do this (possibly also with another command line tool like e.g. awk)?

Thanks.

Edit: to be minimal, I'd be happy with any command that replaces all the spaces between `(` and `.md)` with `-`.

Comment: The general case can be difficult to handle, so I'd recommend searching for a linter, maybe https://github.com/markdownlint/markdownlint (untested).

Comment: What about `(x) 1.md)`? Arguably the space is between `(` and `.md)`.

Comment: @Quasímodo I don't think continuously pointing out unrealistic corner cases is useful for finding an answer to my question. I need just what I asked for, so in your last example I'd need to get `(x).md)`.

Comment: @ Nicola Mori you should post a representative set of input data rather than a minimal contrived one.Because the accuracy depends on that not to mention the iterations needed.

Comment: Do you want to replace spaces within all `(...)` pairs or only those `(...)` pairs that immediately follow a `[...]` pair?

Comment: @EdMorton I had to comment (now deleted) a couple of times for clarification to wring out the last paragraph from the question, which narrows it down *a bit*. Yours was one of my clarification requests. Apparently the asker is not much interested in making this question well-defined, since he explicitly says that pointing out corner cases is unhelpful. Unfortunately sometimes we just have to give up.

Comment: @Quasímodo Yeah I upvoted your comment and the one from guest_7 earlier and saw that comment from the OP and was going to post a response that what's realistic or not is something only they know in their mind, all we can do is point out those non-sunny-day cases to try to help them and get clarity on their actual requirements beyond the one trivial case in the example. I haven't posted an answer due to that comment, thought I'd give them another chance to specify their requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single instance per line, and no nested parentheses, you could do something like this with `match` and `substr`:

```
$ echo '[This is my link](actual bad link.md) other stuff' | awk '
    match($0,/\([^)]*\.md\)/){
      s = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); gsub(/ /,"-", s); 
      print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) s substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}
  '
[This is my link](actual-bad-link.md) other stuff
```

GNU awk has a non-standard extension to capture match groups into an array, but IMO it doesn't buy you much here.

While you could loop the `match` to achieve global replacement, Perl might be a better option ex.

```
$ echo '[This is my link](actual bad link.md) other stuff' | perl -pe '
    s{(\(.*?\.md\))}{$1 =~ s/ /-/gr}ge
  '
[This is my link](actual-bad-link.md) other stuff
```

Comment: The perl option seems to work for me . It does the job also for multiple links on the same line. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `tr` command `tr` with the `-t` flag takes two arguments first the character you want to replace and the second is what to replace it with.

```
cat data | tr -t " " "-"
```

This will replace all spaces with `-` but it should be trivial to pull out the second half of the links. `EDIT: Here is a`grep`command to pull out whats between the`( )`

```
grep -Po '(?<=\().*(?=\))'
```

EDIT: This is an example how this can be done with the core utils.  This script can also be shorted I used the variables to try and make it a little easier to read. `grep` or `sed` or `awk` any of those command could be used to produce the same output.

```
data="[This is my link](actual bad link.md)"
r=$(echo $data | grep -Po '(?<=\().*(?=\))')
n=$(echo $data | grep -Po '(?<=\().*(?=\))' | tr -s ' ' '-')
t=$(echo $data | sed "s|${r}|${n}|")

echo $t
```

Comment: That cannot work. `tr` alone will convert ALL spaces to `-`s, not just those in the target strings, and while `grep` will identify the target strings it (paired with `tr` or not) has no way to modify those strings and put them back into the original text. You need a tool that can actually edit text for this task.

Comment: I have to disagree with that comment I cant add lines in comments so i added an edit to my original answer this is easliy done with core utils and my script could be shortened using the variables to make it a little easier to understand.

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't write a shell script, I said you can't do it with `tr` alone and you can't do it with `grep` even with `tr` and that you need a tool that can actually edit text for this task. You've added that tool that can edit text, `sed`, but even then it'll still fail when `r` contains regexp metachars, `n` contains backreference chars, either of them contain the delimiter chars, other strings that look like `r` exist earlier in the line, etc.